# How to use Play In-app Billing Local Caching?

Tags: android, caching, in-app-billing

I am building app that will check if user have subscription for every different feature he uses. I want to use cache to avoid asking Play through internet every time. 
I haven't found any example. Only [official](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2012/12/in-app-billing-version-3.html) reference which will force me to understand all the code from original convenience classes that Google provides in TrivialDrive example.
I would like to know at least:
1. Does purchased item saved in cache automatically after every purchase made?
2. Is there example for how to use cache?
Thank you very much.

Comment: u can use sqlite forcaching

Comment: Anyone with rooted device can edit db rows and use app services without paying for subscription.

Comment: On the other hand you can encrypt sql db...

Comment: yes local encrytion may help